# Which object is checked by AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I'm trying to use AuthorizeAttribute in my ASP.NET MVC application but I don't understand how it exactly works. When I set user (only for testing purposes) in Index action of Home controller, I give him "Admin" role. Then I check User's property `IsInRole` and it shows me that current user is in "Admin" role. But when I try to get access to action decorated by AuthorizeAttribute with `Roles = "Admin"`, I am redirected to Log in page. So my question is, which object is exactly checked by AuthorizeAttribute - if it isn't User object, so what is it?. My code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("User1"), new[] { "Admin" });

    var isAdmin = User.IsInRole("Admin"); // shows "true" on breakpoint

    return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Contact() // cannot get access to this action
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you login ?

Comment: No, i set user in code because my program won't have default log in option

Comment: All your doing is setting `HttpContext.User` for the current request - its lost as soon as your navigate to another page.

Comment: Ok so is it other option for setting current user's role for the whole website if I can't perform normal logging?